# How to get the working time of a thread in c++/qt?

Tags: multithreading, qt, time, qthread

I'm new in the C++ and QT-Programming and want to get the time in milliseconds that a QThread needed to execute one task. Is there any option for this?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create two signals - one for starting and one for finishing the job. The slot, connected to the start signal, will store the start time like this:

```
mStartTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
```

and the slot, connected to the finish signal, will count the difference like this:

```
qint64 msecs = mStartTime.msecsTo(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
```

Comment: yeah, currently i used something like this. But the problem is, that the thread could be paused (especialy on a single core). So the time is greater than the "real work time"

Comment: Indeed, I can see the problem here. I am afraid, this is the task, that cannot be solved on application level. Only OS itself can count the number of CPU time, allotted to a thread. So I really don't think, Qt can count this exact time. You should look at API of the OS, you are using.